# Как с помощью ajax загрузить контент на страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Необходимо с помощью *Ajax* загружать в файл *index.html* контент с других *html* файлов по клику на соответствующую ссылку.

Вот мой код, но он почему то не работает, что в нем не так:

```js
var view = document.querySelector(".view");
view.addEventListener("click", loadView);

function loadView(event) {
  var target = event && event.target || window.event.srcElement;
  var href = target.getAttribute("href");
  event.preventDefault();
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
      view.innerHTML = "";
      view.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", href);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```css
.categories {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.categories a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.view {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.view img {
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <a id="home" href="index.html">Главная</a>
  <a id="city" href="city.html">Города</a>
  <a id="people" href="people.html">Люди</a>
  <a id="nature" href="nature.html">Природа</a>
  <a id="animals" href="animals.html">Животные</a>
</div>
<div class="view">
  <img src="img/city-1.jpg" alt="city-1">
  <img src="img/people-1.jpg" alt="people-1">
  <img src="img/nature-1.jpg" alt="nature-1">
  <img src="img/animals-1.jpg" alt="animals-1">
</div>
```

Comment: "что в нем не так" - В элементе с классом `view` нет элементов с аттрибутом `href`.

Comment: @Igor спасибо разобрался благодаря вашему замечанию

Comment: Не за что. Успехов в программировании.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно так:

```js
var categories = document.querySelector(".categories");
var view = document.querySelector(".view");
categories.addEventListener("click", loadView);

function loadView(event) {
  var target = event && event.target || window.event.srcElement;
  var href = target.getAttribute("href");
  event.preventDefault();
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
      view.innerHTML = "";
      view.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", href);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```css
.categories {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.categories a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.view {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.view img {
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <a id="home" href="home.html">Главная</a>
  <a id="city" href="city.html">Города</a>
  <a id="people" href="people.html">Люди</a>
  <a id="nature" href="nature.html">Природа</a>
  <a id="animals" href="animals.html">Животные</a>
</div>
<div class="view">
  <img src="img/city-1.jpg" alt="city-1">
  <img src="img/people-1.jpg" alt="people-1">
  <img src="img/nature-1.jpg" alt="nature-1">
  <img src="img/animals-1.jpg" alt="animals-1">
</div>
```